# Cannot extract genre metadata from song using MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns

Tags: android, metadata

I'm currently working on a music player for Android devices.

To index the Music files from the system, I wrote this function in Kotlin to get a Cursor for all the music in the phones filesystem, along with its metadata using `MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns`:

```
private fun getMusicCursor(resolver: ContentResolver): Cursor? {
    Log.i(this::class.simpleName, "Getting music cursor.")

    return resolver.query(
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        arrayOf(
            AudioColumns._ID, // 0
            AudioColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, // 1
            AudioColumns.TITLE, // 2
            AudioColumns.ARTIST, // 3
            AudioColumns.ALBUM, // 4
            AudioColumns.GENRE, // 5
            AudioColumns.YEAR, // 6
            AudioColumns.TRACK, // 7
            AudioColumns.DURATION // 8
        ),
        AudioColumns.IS_MUSIC + "=1", null,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER
    )
}
```

The problem is that when I add the Genre column [`AudioColumns.GENRE`], the code always fails and will throw this exception if outside of a try-catch statement:

```
2020-08-21 09:14:26.077 16658-16715/org.oxycblt.auxio E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: org.oxycblt.auxio, PID: 16658
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column genre
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:437)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:962)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:890)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:846)
        at org.oxycblt.auxio.music.MusicLoader.getMusicCursor(MusicLoader.kt:95)
        at org.oxycblt.auxio.music.MusicLoader.findMusic(MusicLoader.kt:39)
        at org.oxycblt.auxio.music.MusicLoader.<init>(MusicLoader.kt:29)
        at org.oxycblt.auxio.music.MusicRepository.init(MusicRepository.kt:25)
        at org.oxycblt.auxio.loading.LoadingViewModel$startMusicRepo$1.invokeSuspend(LoadingViewModel.kt:41)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:740)
```

This also affects other genre-related values, such as `GENRE_ID` and the [deprecated] `GENRE_KEY` constants. I could use `MediaMetadataRetriever` to get the genre value, but that takes alot longer than using a Cursor.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found a solution to my problem, you can first declare a Genre cursor using something like:

```
genreCursor = resolver.query(
    Genres.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    arrayOf(
        Genres._ID, // 0
        Genres.NAME // 1
    ),
    null, null,
    Genres.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER
)
```

Then use the cursor to create a list of every genre in the system.

After that, when you want to load the music, you can create a song Cursor that is filtered based on that Genre's ID, like this:

```
songCursor = resolver.query(
    Genres.Members.getContentUri("external", genreId),
    arrayOf(
        AudioColumns._ID, // 0
        AudioColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, // 1
        AudioColumns.TITLE, // 2
        AudioColumns.ARTIST, // 3
        AudioColumns.ALBUM, // 4
        AudioColumns.YEAR, // 5
        AudioColumns.TRACK, // 6
        AudioColumns.DURATION // 7
    ),
    AudioColumns.IS_MUSIC + "=1", null,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER
)
```

Repeat this for every genre, and you can load the genres with the music just fine, albeit in a weird way.